# How To Use "Opinion Lexicon" On NLTK?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, nltk-trainer

I downloaded it:

```
nltk.download('all')
```

Now I wish to add the dataset to my classifier. Does anyone know a tutorial?